# Performing subtraction on same column and same column based on conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
employeeid  SalaryType  Amount
------------------------------
100         w           200
100         s           100
210         w           300
210         s           50
300         w           90
300         s           30
```

based on these entries I want to retrieve the following result:

```
emloyeeid   Amount (difference between W and S)
-----------------------------------------------
100         100
210         250
300         60
```

how do I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

For example..

```
SELECT t1.employeeid, t1.amount - t2.amount FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE salaryType = 'w') t1,
  (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE salaryType = 's') t2
WHERE t1.employeeid = t2.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to solve your issue

```
SELECT employeeid, t1.amount - t2.amount FROM
mytable AS t1 LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 
ON t1.employeeid = t2.employeeid 
AND t1.SalaryType = 'w' AND t2.SalaryType = 's'
```